# Redirect all requests to specific directory without changing URL .htaccess (Deploying Angular project)

Tags: angular, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, directory

I have an Angular project and I want to deploy it on a specific folder (not root) so something like this :
http://localhost/folder/index.html
So i need to redirect all requests on this path without changing URL.

The following works fine when the index.html is at root (so, http://localhost/index.html) :

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

So I tried to change this code like this to work with my project :

```
RewriteRule ^ /folder/index.html
```

I works fine with this request : http://localhost/folder/abcd but not with http://localhost/folder/abcd/efgh, http://localhost/folder/abcd/efgh/.../..../.....

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention in your question FROM which URL TO which URL you want to rewrite? For better understanding of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Actually I need all URLs to be redirect to the content of this url : http://localhost/folder/index.html but with no redirection (i don't want the URL in the browser to change).

So for example if you type : http://localhost/folder/blablabla, http://localhost/folder/blabla/blabla, http://localhost/folder/blabla/blabla/blabla, etc. You have to have the content of http://localhost/folder/index.html. I will manage the request then with javascript to adapt content of the html page !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please place your .htaccess file inside folder named `folder`. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

As mentioned in the comments: In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```